# Unable to Move/Resize App windows in Desktop after enabling multiple Workspaces

Tags: raspbian

In Raspbian OS, Having problem with moving  &/or resizing app windows after adding multiple Workspaces/Desktops.   Mouse cursor Hover over top & edges of selected display shows anticipated control functions but left/right click mouse function not accepted.

WEB’s work around is as follows:

Place mouse on /select App window you wish to work with.  Alt+Space keys (normally mouse right click) opens a pull-down which allows the selection of the normal actions.

This works but interrupts the flow as Application windows top right icons do not work & moving new apps out of the way no longer smooth of normal windowed OSes.

Comment: Consider skipping the first two paragraphs next time you ask.

Comment: @MN_CaveMan perhaps your systems are out of date. Run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. If that doesn't fix it, open a support ticket with Openbox (assuming that's your window manager, it's the default) [here](http://openbox.org/wiki/Openbox:Contribute#Bug_reports).

Answer (score 1):

The way to clear this issue is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364472/cant-resize-or-move-windows-on-raspberry-pi)

Addition information on this issue:
The core problem appears to be that the position at which the cursor is displayed is out of sync with the position that the window api has it at. This can be demonstrated by opening a small window such as a terminal window, then:

1. Placing the cursor on the title bar of the window and clicking and holding the left mouse key. The cursor is unchanged and you are unable to drag the window.
2. Release the mouse key and drift the mouse pointer towards the bottom of the screen.
3. Watch for a change in the cursor, in my case this happens at about the depth of the title bar below the displayed title bar.
4. Left click and hold the mouse button. The cursor will change to the crossed arrow move cursor and the window will follow your mouse movements.